# Laptop stand with space for keyboard

Tags: laptop, keyboards, docking-stations

I'm looking for a highly portable laptop stand which has space for a keyboard to live underneath the laptop. I can touch type so no issue with not seeing the keyboard. My current stand forces the laptop screen to be too far away.

Answer (score 1):

I use something similar to this in the office, which allows my keyboard to be parked under the leading edge of the stand.

https://www.dell.com/en-uk/work/shop/r-go-riser-flexible-laptop-stand-adjustable-black/apd/ab538697

Answer (score 0):

I've got one from MOFT. It's an adhesive laptop stand, which is extremely portable. But you just can't place your keyboard under the laptop.